# How to install the perl module DBD::Sybase on Unix (Mac OSX)?

Tags: macos, perl, unix, makefile

I'm having trouble installing the perl module DBD::Sybase on my Mac.  Please provide procedure on how to do this.

Comment: can you detail your steps? did you install with brew?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These instructions helped me get it setup properly (http://ddiguru.com/blog/61-building-dbdsybase-on-unix-systems).
It didn't work for me when I used the latest versions.  I had to install Freetds-0.82 and DBD-Sybase-1.08 to get it working.